# is it bad practise to store a table in a database with no primary key?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently working on a list implementation in python that stores a persistent list as a database:
https://github.com/DarkShroom/sqlitelist

I am tackling a design consideration, it seems that SQLite allows me store the data without a primary key?

```
self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM unnamed LIMIT 1 OFFSET {}'.format(key))
```

this line of code can retrieve by absolute row reference

Is this bad practise? will I loose the data order at any point? Perhaps it's OKAY with sqlite, but my design will not translate to other database engines? Any thoughts from people more familiar with databases would be helpful. I am writing this so I don't have to deal with databases!

Comment: SQLite generates a primary key for you internally, called the `ROWID`.

Comment: In RDB theory, there is no concept of ordering in tables, so LIMIT 1 OFFSET {} would give you an implementation dependent (?) result.

Comment: Do not use string formatting to construct SQL queries; use parameterized queries instead. (Imagine `key='3; drop table unnamed'`; use `self.c.execute('select * from unnamed limit 1 offset %s', key)`--or whatever format your library specifies--instead.)

Comment: thanks, i just found this "ROWID" by playing around with this sqlitebrowser gui thing i have

i guess i am at a design decision then, i would like to make MySQLList maybe also

well,  think for the moment, i will try and make a "play it safe" code, where i have my own id column and use this, but also code a fast one relying on how sqlite is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) says:

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.

So you cannot simply use OFFSET to identify rows.

A PRIMARY KEY constraint just tells the database that is must enforce UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints on the PK columns. If you do not declare a PRIMARY KEY, these constraints are not automatically enforced, but this does not change the fact that you have to identify your rows somehow when you want to access them.

---

The easiest way to store list entries is to have the position in the list as a separate column. (If your program takes up most of its time inserting or deleting list entries, it might be a better idea to store the list not as an array but as a linked list, i.e., the database does not store the position but a pointer to the next entry.)

Comment: thanks

so i refactored a bit and removed my autoincrement id when i found out about the _rowid_

what i am still unsure of is whether I can rely on the _rowid_ then, it appears it's not a primary key but retains the order of the list?
So I get I shouldn't be using "offset" but I could perhaps order by _rowid_ and be okay?

If this is still wrong, i guess i go back to a primary key (id)... but I sort of liked the one column table, like it meets expectations of a user.

thanks for the linked list idea, however i feel that i will stick to extremely suboptimal insert (for now)

Comment: i mean with the linked list thing, delete is okay at the moment, no problem, also add to the end of the table is okay... for my usage it is great, and i figure i can document this..... Sorry the question to ask anyway, if you may, can I guarantee the order of the _rowid_ then? Also would a primary key be faster for any reason? Thanks

Comment: If you want to use the `rowid`, you should make one of your actual columns [an alias for it](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). As for how it behaves, see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: thank you for linking me to that documentation, i now get it (i find the sqlite documentation quite extensive sorry).

okay so the alias is my answer, i had this design before by accident and it wastes no extra resources and runs as fast as possible (with the indexing search etc).

the correct design then is the primary key column i had before